# How do I prevent an egg cracking while hard boiling it?

Tags: eggs, boiling

Sometimes when I cook hard boiled eggs they will crack in the saucepan, and some of the egg will seep out into the water.

Am I boiling the water too vigorously, or can I add something to the water to prevent it?

Comment: [People are now asking for proof about this](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37632/does-pricking-eggs-before-boiling-them-reduce-cracking)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I used the method here before with good success: http://simplyrecipes.com/recipes/how_to_make_perfect_hard_boiled_eggs/

Basically you start with the eggs in the pan with cold water and bring the water to temperature, right when it reaches boiling you pull the heat back and let the eggs cook for 10 minutes.

You don't need a full on boil to hard boil the eggs.

Comment: In my experience, steeping for 8 minutes is plenty and tends to reduce the greening of the yolks. That also gives you a buffer if it takes a bit of time to get back to the stove or fumble for a minute to prepare the water bath.

Comment: This above method is how I hard boil eggs. It does a few things. First, it lets you put the eggs in the pan carefully so they don't crack from that. Second, you are not shocking the eggshell nor causing sudden expansion off the inside of the eggs (IOW making the inside bigger than the outside). The cooking is more gentle so the egg is cooked more evenly. I bathe my freshly boiled eggs in ice water for an hour to halt cooking sooner. It helps keep the eggs from getting tough, and it also Aids in shelling the eggs because the sudden chill makes the egg white sluff off the membrane.

Comment: Now, if you are going to make tea eggs or iron eggs which is to start boiling the eggs a second time in a spiced tea of sorts, you want to do that mostly right away. If you refrigerate your eggs over night then use them for tea eggs, they tend to expand grotesquely.

Comment: Being a perfectionist this would drive me crazy, then I discovered this method and now, no more cracked hard boiled eggs!

Answer (score 29):

Before you submerge the egg, prick the large end of the shell with a (clean!) thumb tack or safety pin.  This will allow the trapped air bubbles - which are normally responsible for cracking - to escape during the boiling process.

Also take care to avoid any impacts:

- Don't overcrowd the pot - the eggs should form a single *sparse* layer;
- Use a tongs or spoon to lower the eggs into the boiling water - or start with cold water with the eggs already in the pot.
- Make sure you use enough water - cover the eggs by at least an inch.

P.S. Even though the above should *always* prevent cracking, if you're still having problems, you can add some vinegar to the water.  This will *not* help with cracking but it *will* make the eggs set quicker if they *do* crack and mitigate the nasty mess.  I don't do this anymore, but something to remember if you're desperate (i.e. if the eggs are very old).

Comment: This method also helps skinning the egg when cooked :)

Answer (score 4):

As eggs develop more air as they get older (which is why bad eggs float, fresh eggs sink,and old eggs stand up in water) you are more likely to get cracked eggs with older eggs, and if you plunge them in to hot water.

If you are doing it for hard boiling then you might be better using a technique like ManiacZX describes where you bring the eggs to the boil in cold water, then turn the heat off and leave them with a lid on for 10-12 mins.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to add a caution for simple over-cooking.  I'm a soft-boiled fan, myself, but generally I think the risk of cracking is greater the more the eggs rattle around in boiling water with their liquid steaming inside.  Low and slow makes great eggs.

Answer (score 3):

For the first time I used a special rack to suspend the egg in the water without it resting on the bottom of the saucepan and for the first time ever it didn't crack.

Any other time I have tried all the above and it didn't help.

I'm now sure it's because of the contact with the hot surface of the pan before the water has a chance to disperse the heat so that it doesn't rise dramatically above 100 deg c

Answer (score 2):

There is an air bubble at the base of the egg as shown below. As you cook the egg the air bubble expands and cracks the shell. To prevent the shell from cracking, gently pierce the air bubble with a sharp, pointy knife. It allows the expanding air to escape.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to fill the pot that you are boiling your egg with to at least an inch higher than the egg layer. This will prevent the egg from bouncing around too much. I've been using the stuffs written here in boiling eggs: http://knowhowtoboileggs.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-hard-boil-eggs.html

Answer (score 1):

I trained as a chef; the way to do this is as follows.

The egg cracks for a number of reasons which are mainly due to a change of pressure within the egg itself. You never want to put a hole in the shell, add salt to the water or frankly any of the other suggestions on this page above, and it's not due to eggs banging about in the pan (that one did make me laugh).

1. All you do is put the egg or eggs (I used to do this at work in a big pan 30 eggs in it).
2. Pour boiling water half way up the egg.
3. You will hear a hissing sound as the pressure in the egg changes.
4. When it stops (after about 15 to 30 seconds) put the pan on heat and cook as normal.

Occasionally an egg will crack anyway due to having an uneven thickness of shell but there isn't much you can do about it. It's best to take the eggs out of the fridge (if that’s where you keep them, but that’s about all you can do).

Comment: "occasionally an egg will crack anyway...but there isn't much you can do about it" sure there is: take some of the advice in the answers you dismissed. For example, the accepted answer (bring to a boil then let cook without heat) definitely works well.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with comments from Jefromi, for one. Everything should have a logical explanation and root causes. The procedure for boiling up to 30 eggs looks interesting. Similar is the process by Jeff Bullas...

My assessment - It is the pressure buildup inside the shell that causes cracks. If I boil eggs slowly I can see tiny bubbles coming out from the shell at several places, this is the process of relieving the pressure naturally.

My own experience: If I boil cold eggs straight from the frig and raise the temperature of water on high flame very quickly it almost always cracks.  If I boil slow after warming up the eggs at 40 deg C, results are much better. Pin hole at the bubble end also helps but may be termed un-hygienic? Now-a-days I warm up the egg to ~40 deg C in warmed water, then put eggs in another pan, pour boiling water halfway, wait 30 sec, pour in more of the same water till submerged, cook for 3 minutes on low flame, switch off, and eggs are ready in another 12 minutes (may be lower time is possible, not checked. Results are quite good, almost no cracks over many attempts.

Comment: My comment had nothing to do with whether there are logical explanations or root causes. If anything, it was the opposite - someone said there was nothing you could do about it, and I disagreed, pointing to answers that suggested things you could do about it. Maybe you disagreed with the answer I was commenting on, written by user30924?

Answer (score 0):

Pre warm chilled eggs in a bowl of hot tap water for 5 mins and put them straight into boiling water. Never crack!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it's the result of extreme temperature changes ie fridge to boiling water or worse boiling water + salt (higher temperature). Take eggs from fridge and warm them under hot tap. Submerge eggs at least 1 inch below in non salted boiling water. Viola no cracks.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the pricking eggs at the rounded end, and also leave the top of the pot off.  I never have cracked eggs.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry, but I strongly disagree with the air bubble theory. I have had too many eggs crack from the bottom
Of the shell (small end). MY  theory on that is... the eggs have imperfections from the laying process which causes a lot of cracks.

The best method I have found for keeping eggs from cracking is to slowly bring them to a boil, boil SLOWLY for about 10 minutes, then turn off the fire, cover the pan with a fitted top, then let the water cool naturally.

By the time you can handle the eggs comfortably, they should be done, no green on the yolks and few to no cracked eggs. Drain the water, then bounce the eggs in the pan (top on if cooking a large amount of eggs) to crack the shells. The cooler the water is, the easier they will peel.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Add salt before your water gets hot